# No component factory found for HomePage in Ionic Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I just created an app with Ionic cli using the template with the menu.

I've setup all test configuration. My TestBed looks like this

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: StatusBar, useFactory: () => StatusBarMock.instance() },
    { provide: SplashScreen, useFactory: () => SplashScreenMock.instance() },
  ],
});
```

Mocks are from `ionic-mocks`

```
import { StatusBarMock, SplashScreenMock } from 'ionic-mocks';
```

My test passes

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyApp);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('component is created', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

But I'm getting this "warning":

> ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'No component factory found for HomePage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?',

`HomePage` is on `MyApp`'s `@NgModule` on `entryComponents`. Do I have to include it in the TestBed as well? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the component to entry components:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  entryComponents: [MyApp]  <-------------------
});
```

Or you can import your module with components you want to test:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyApp],
  imports: [
    AppModuleWithHomePageComponent,  <--------------
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
```

Comment: There aren't modules for pages, at least not in the generated app from `ionic start sidemenu`... But that makes sense, I will try to create it later. I guess none of the apps Ionic generate cares about testing...

Comment: @BrunoLM, I've updated my answer. Just add `MyApp` to the entry components of the testing module